# Weird Index activity on mysql Join

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a `countries` table structured like this with an index on the iso2 column:

---

[image]

---

When doing a normal select query, the iso2 index works fine:

---

[image]

---

But when joining with another table on the iso2, it behaves very strangely:

---

[image]

---

First of all it says `NULL` possible_keys but then it still uses it? Then it also says 256 rows which is the whole table. It runs very slow on big updates so I can tell it is not using the index. What's the problem here?

EDIT: Also, if I take out the `id` column from the iso2 index (see the first picture), then it will say no index being used on the join.

---

More info: I have been trying to normalize my data and using a `country_id` instead of a `country`. I was updating tables with the `country_id` when i noticed it was going really slow. A few EXPLAIN's led me to find out the index was not being used. Maybe it has something to do with iso2 being char(2)?

I was populating the country_id like this:

```
UPDATE leads
LEFT JOIN countries on leads.country=countries.iso2
SET leads.country_id=countries.id
```

This query took almost 40 seconds for about 100k rows on the `leads` table.

Answer (score 0):

That `EXPLAIN` means that it is doing a full index scan, which is not ideal, but is not necessarily bad; in this case, it is fine.  The `iso2` index is a `covering index`, which means that it contains all of the columns that are needed from that table for this query.  Basically, the query optimizer decided that instead of finding the row that is needed from the index and then reading that row from the table to get the `id`, it would just go to the next part of the index since that is faster.

I would have expected the optimizer to use a reference on the index, but apparently it decided that that would not be beneficial.  Since the index is small, I wouldn't worry about it not using a reference on the index.

A few other points:

- Can you please elaborate on "It runs very slow on big updates"?
- Is the table using MyISAM or InnoDB?
- `countries.id` could probably be changed to a `SMALLINT UNSIGNED`; that's almost the same as `INT(5)`, but uses 2 bytes instead of 4.
- `CHAR(2)` is the best data type for `iso2`

Comment: I added an example update. It is using MyISAM but I tried switching engines and nothing changed. What I don't understand is, how come the `SELECT` seems to only need to browse 1 row while the join is doing a "full index scan"?